# Parsing data from a txt file in separate arrays using Matlab

Tags: matlab, parsing, text

I am trying to save columns of numbers from a text file in separate array so that they can be plotted. My code works fine for the first column, but I can't seem to save the later arrays. In case of putting `Y(j)`, the array is expanding to 38 columns instead. I also tried using `Y(1:19)` but that just saves the last value only.

```
m = dlmread("result.txt");

X = zeros (1,19);

for i = 1:19
    x = m(i);

    X (i) = x;
end

Y = zeros (1,19);

for j = 20:38
    y = m(j);

    Y (j) = y;
end

plot (X,Y,'*')
```

Here's the data from my text file:

```
-117.482071 , 38.587502 , 1889.332764 
-127.234932 , -134.117035 , 1862.899170 
-295.751495 , -137.280533 , 1870.713989 
-396.392212 , -342.627838 , 1797.450195 
-364.200378 , -82.991661 , 1732.802490 
30.170357 , -149.174057 , 1912.513794 
137.002335 , -363.414001 , 1893.756470 
132.693115 , -124.178337 , 1769.763306 
-129.690857 , -365.272583 , 1854.689697 
-132.590271 , -530.044312 , 1816.501099 
-230.024750 , -573.607178 , 1800.884766 
-192.102402 , -904.118896 , 1666.393433 
-192.102402 , -1241.659302 , 1666.393433 
-37.203903 , -579.247864 , 1821.582275 
-37.203903 , -938.084900 , 1821.582275 
-37.203903 , -1275.625244 , 1821.582275 
-369.565674 , -126.264359 , 1743.577148 
133.411316 , -164.050949 , 1790.428833 
-126.466972 , -61.835381 , 1865.466309
```

Comment: Why not `X = m(:, 1); Y = m(:, 2);`? Your loops are unnecessary.

Comment: Since you have commas and whitespaces in your `result.txt`, you should specify a delimiter in `dlmread`, i.e. use `m = dlmread("result.txt", ",")`. Then, `m` is a 19 x 3 array, and the solution from @beaker will perfectly work for you. Without specifying a delimiter, `m` will be a 19 x 5 array with 0s in column 2 and 4.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot.